# Printing PHP variable using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am trying to print a dynamic database variable using javascript. My code is simple. i am using :

```
    var name = "<? echo $listname; ?>";
    var listName = 'ADD A MEMBER TO "' + name + '"';
```

What i get printed is: ADD A MEMBER TO "" < !--? echo $listname; ?--> (without the space).
Im guessing for some reason the "<" character is a shortcut for it. Is there any way to bypass this ? I simply need it to print it without the < !-- -->.

Thank you in advance

Comment: A.O. yes you can, he just has a unbelievably bad syntax error. check the opening tag of his php.

Comment: PHP runs on the server and **generates** the javascript code that runs **later** on the client. So when your javascripts runs later on the client. It sees the literal value that **was** in the PHP variable $listname a while ago. The PHP code that created the javascript code has left and gone home. Long before the javascript gets to run on the client.

Comment: Hi Ryan. The value for the name doesn't change at all, so technically even if javascript uses an "out of date" value, it will be the correct one. My problem is that the code gets the <!-- --> html ignore tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is usually only possible if your JavaScript code is inside a `.php` file.  Your server might also need the opening PHP tag to be `<?php` as well.  You can use `<?` as an open tag only if `short_open_tag` is configured.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag for more information on that.

Here's a quick example how I made this work running on PHP 5.4.15 in Windows 7:

```
// omg.php

<?php $listname = "win"; ?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>Stuff</title>
</head>
<script>
    var name     = '<?php echo $listname ?>';
    var listName = 'ADD A MEMBER TO "' + name + '"';
    console.log(listName);
</script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

The above sample should print `ADD A MEMBER TO "win"` in the console.

Comment: I'll try that now. The original file IS php however the js function is in an external js file. i'll let you know

Comment: Thank you ! that was it. the original code was fine, just needed it in the php file. great answer cypher +1

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax error in your opening php tag. in general, it is better practice to get the variable from ajax, but it is possible to use this method, though its not really a great practice. also, don't use double quotes in javascript code. ever.

`var name = '<?php echo json_encode($listname); ?>';`

edit:

its possible you're trying to add a php tag inside of a php statement that hasn't been closed. you need to use the concatenation operator if so.

Comment: thanks . I've tried your code however i get the exact same effect. <!--?php echo json_encode($listname); ?--> Its still marked to be ignored.

Comment: there is something else at play here then. this is not normal behaviour for php. if you provide more code from the file we could be able to understand the exact problem, but with the limited info you've provided i'm not really sure.

Comment: If you view the html source you shouldn't see your PHP code. It looks like your server isn't compiling the PHP. <?= is a PHP short tag but you will need to configure your server to allow this.

Comment: Here is the JS and what i get in source code. I removed the short tag but still the same problem. http://screencast.com/t/VUVA9qW8d

Comment: @Bdevelle, this would indicate the PHP code is not running. Is the file a .php file? Is there any other PHP in the same file which is working (or not working)?

Comment: Yep. its a php file and all php in it is working fine. u will try placing the JS function inside the php file as suggested by Cypher